# Case Statement Illegal Expression SQL

Tags: sql, case, teradata

I don't get where the error msg 'Illegal expression in WHEN clause of CASE expression' comes from by running this snippet in Teradata SQL

```
CASE 
  WHEN f_ev1.PROCESS_NO IN 
    (
      SELECT
        numbers.PROCESS_NO
      FROM numbers
      WHERE 
        numbers.FLAG = 1
      GROUP BY 1 --no duplicates
    ) THEN 2
END AS Status,
```

If I write IN (*some numbers*) it works just fine. But it is a list that consists of 50 unique values that can possibly change over time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62263285/2527905

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is that you can load the fifty values into another table and you can join that table with the main table

table_50 - Table with 50 unique values
main_tbl - Main table

```
insert into table_50 ( process_no ) SELECT numbers.PROCESS_NO FROM numbers WHERE numbers.FLAG = 1 GROUP BY 1 ;

Select case when b.process_no is null then 2  end as status from main_table a
left join table_50 b
on a.process_no= b.process_no
```

From a performance perspective, this is more effective and you can also update the values in the table_50 as per your requirement